# tinymce automatic list items

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, tinymce

I am using the tinymce lib.
this is my code:

```
<div class="beschreibung"></div>

<script>
tinymce.init({
   selector: '.beschreibung',
   inline: true,
   menubar: false,
   skin: "oxide-dark",
   toolbar: 'bold italic bullist',
   plugins: ['lists','autoresize'],
   toolbar_location: 'bottom',
   language: 'de'
}); 
</script>
```

This works fine.

Example:

[image]

But now I would realize an automatic creation of list items.
My idea:

I write `"- "` (a single line with a space)
This should create a list item automatically.

Is there a tinymce solution available ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `textpattern` plugin provides this functionality for TinyMCE. It will match against certain patterns while typing and perform an action, such as converting a line starting with `-`  into a list when pressing enter. You can add other custom patterns as well by configuring the `textpattern_patterns` setting, however the default should do what you require.

See https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/textpattern/ for more information.

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to off this functionality.

Text patterns are now on by default: `text_patterns: false` turns the functionality off.